# SecureString хешировать MD5

Tags: c#, wpf, md5, криптография

Есть метод который принимает пароль и возвращает его уже захешированным в MD5. Поначалу я использовал не `SecureString` а просто `string` в которую записывал `Password` взятый из контролла и проблем не было. Сейчас прочел что при таком подходе строка храниться в памяти процессора, поэтому рекомендуется использовать `SecurePassword` и передавать на сервер так. Собственно теперь из за этого возникает ошибка :

> Ошибка CS1503  Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "SecureString" в "char[]".

```
    internal static string GetHash(System.Security.SecureString passHASH) //тут
    {
        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
        byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(passHASH));
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Можно конечно написать так

```
  byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(passHASH.ToString()));
```

Но не пофиксит ли это использование `SecureString` ?

Comment: Что значит _пофиксит ли это использование_? Да и не получите вы значение из `SecureString` простым `SecureString.ToString()`.

Comment: Значит - не будут ли потеряны выигрыши в безопасности от использования `SecureString` при переводе `passHASH` в обычную `string` ? потому что `SecureString ` в MD5 не хешируется.

Comment: Если у Вас есть контрол, в который вводится пароль и у него есть явный string с содержимым, то Ваше изменение string => secureString защиту не повысит. И, если уж, действительно волноваться за защиту, то MD5 для хеша пароля ни как не годится.

Comment: @eblomyac я использую `PasswordBox` у которого есть 2 свойства - `Password` и `SecurePassword`. Я хочу понять какой вариант лучше и если второй то как получить хеш от  `SecurePassword` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переводите в обычную строку

```
public static string convertToUNSecureString(SecureString secstrPassword)
{
    IntPtr unmanagedString = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        unmanagedString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(secstrPassword);
        return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedString);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(unmanagedString);
    }
}
```

А потом считаете хэш, но если у вас исходно есть обычная строка, то лучше вычислить с начала хэш, а потом конвертировать в SecureString.